# Unable to make a Instance Method that prints

Tags: java

Task is to make an instance method that prints out some variables (with formatting).
So far I have:

```
public report(){
System.out.printf("%6.2f",radius+"%7.3",circumference()+"%9.4",area());
```

This obviously comes up with errors so not sure what to do here.

error message:

> "Java: Invalid method declaration; return type required".

Comment: Post error message too

Comment: Post complete code so we can test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Declare the method to return void.

> public void report()

Also, make a format string, then put the arguments

> System.out.printf("%6.2f %7.3X %9.4X",radius,circumference(),area());

X can be

> %i or %d    int
>   %c  char
>   %f  float 
>   %s  string

Note: System.out.printf does not return strings, it prints on the screen, thus the void type.
For returning consider StringBuilder s

Answer (score 0):

Change to :

```
public void report()
```

If you are not returning anything you use void, else return type

Comment: But surely we are returning the print string? Which is the:      System.out.printf("%6.2f",radius+"%7.3",circumference()+"%9.4",area());

Comment: But system.out.print prints the line. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

When defining the method, we must designate the return type(e.g.int, boolean, String,etc). If method does not return anything, it's type is void.